# clear all form input box after submit form using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, tailwind-css

want to clear all input box form after submit data

here is my code:

```
function GSetup() {
        
        const [gName, setGName] = useState("");
    
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        
          useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(getGNames());
          }, [dispatch]);
        
          const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        
            dispatch(
              addGName(
                { 
                  gn_name: gName, 
                  su_id: userInfo._id 
                }
               
              )
            );
          };
        return (  ​);
}
```

I use this `setState` on `onSubmitHandler` function but its not working

```
this.setState({
      gn_name: ''
    });
```

Comment: you need to use `setGName('') `.  you are using hook for state handle so you need to use `setGName` to update `gName` state .

Comment: Yes it works, I miss these instead of setState. Thanks @monesulhaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```js
function GSetup() {
        
  const [gName, setGName] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getGNames());
    }, [dispatch]);
  
    const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      dispatch(
        addGName(
          { 
            gn_name: gName, 
            su_id: userInfo._id 
          }
         
        )
      );
      setGName('')   
    };


  return (  ​);
}
```

`this.setState({})` does not work outside of `classComponent`